# HttpPostRequest Text+File in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, http, post, httpwebrequest

HttpPostRequest with Files only in VB2008 is easy:

```
    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
        wc.UploadFile("http://server.de/exemple.php", "c:\test.png")
    End Using
```

But I want POST Text + Files in one POST (username, password, file).
But, how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). You will need to use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and manually [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) the request according to [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.txt).

Comment: Do you have an example for that? I found an exemple for text only, but not with files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data